# CakePHP not inserting registered date on user registration

Tags: php, cakephp, registration

I'm using this code in my action to register a new user:

```
public function register() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Register');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been created. You may now login with your username and password.', 'default', array('class' => 'success-flash'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('There was an error creating your account.', 'default', array('class' => 'error-flash'));
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `regisered` field in my database users table is always `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. How can I make Cake insert a correct date into this field? Thanks.

Comment: What data are you posting? What is the column type in the db? As the answer below states,  you can use Cake's automatic field to keep track of when records are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to cakephp conventions the field should be named `created`.

Cakephp will then automatically fill that field.

It's written at the bottom of that [paragraph](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#creating-the-blog-database).

More detailed docs, but for the 1.3 version: [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1002/Creating-Database-Tables#created-and-modified-1015).